# How to Add Print Control on MapQuest Map using Javascript

Tags: mapquest

In map quest web site, their map has a print menu item on top of the menu. I want to have the same print button on my custom map quest map. I checked the JavaScript API and there is nothing for print for map options.

For example I can add a Large Zoom Control on the map with the following code snippet.

```
map.addControl(
               new MQA.LargeZoom(),
               new MQA.MapCornerPlacement(MQA.MapCorner.TOP_LEFT, new MQA.Size(5, 5))
);
```

There is no MQA.Print Control in the Javascript API in the following url
http://developer.mapquest.com/web/documentation/sdk/javascript/v7.0/api/MQA.LargeZoom.html

Does anyone know how Print Control can be added to the map using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

There is no controls defined in mapquest for printing the map.
 place the button for print in the page and use the following jquery function when the button clicked.

```
$('SelectorToPrint').printElement();
```

The map should be loaded in particular element. so that you can print the map only.